# PyCharm debugger doesn't show objects' content: "Unable to get repr for <type 'list>"

Tags: macos, pycharm, pydev

Debugging with PyCharm (happens on multiple versions) I'm unable to correctly view some lists and dictionaries (other are presented correctly).
In the view window the object's name is presented with the message:
`{list} Unable to get repr for <type 'list>`
or
`{dict} Unable to get repr for <type 'dict'>`

An update:
In one of my attempts, I received the following message from the debugger (presented instead of the value of one of the list variable):

> Unable to display children:Error resolving variables Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File "/Applications/PyCharm
>   CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line
>   1004, in do_it
>   _typeName, valDict = pydevd_vars.resolve_compound_variable(self.thread_id, self.frame_id,
>   self.scope, self.attributes) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not
>   iterable

I'll appreciate any idea as for what may cause this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add an minimal working example

Comment: The problem doesn't reproduce with small samples or with just any script. I'm trying to understand what could be potential causes for such an error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It turned out the problem is due to usage of rpyc.py: The process I was debugging was called through rpyc and while I was debugging it, the calling process received a timeout on the rpyc connection.
I think that this caused variables, passed through rpc to lose integrity so the debugger couldn't present them correctly.

The solution was to downgrade rpyc.py to version 3.3.0 (I was on 3.4.2).
My colleague, Nurit Izraelov, correctly suggested the rpyc.py version may be the blame.

Thanks all!

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain where exactly `rpyc.py` can be found, and how to downgrade it ? I have looked in my project's interpreter packages (in the settings window), and couldn't find any mention of `rpyc`.

Comment: Hi, rpyc is a library, so in Pycharm you would go to PyCharm menu -> Preferences...     In the dialog, on the left hand side select your project -> Project interpreter.
At the top of the right pane select your interpreter, from the drop box and then, at the bottom left the + sign. In the newly opened dialog type in 'rpyc' and on the bottom right check 'Specify version' and select your desigered version. Click the Install version button and oks. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I meant that I did look at my project's interpreter libs, and I don't seem to have any `rpyc` installed. Looks like I'm facing a different issue, unless you are suggesting that I should *install* the `rpyc` lib to fix this issue ? (Nor do I seem to have anything named `pydev`, seems to be handled by Pycharm somewhere else).

Comment: If you don't have rpyc installed and want to use it you can install it following the instructions I wrote above. In any case I strongly recommend **against** using rpc (which rpyc wraps) in any way, this is an outdated and problematic technology in my mind. I prefer using queues or REST APIs to communicate between processes.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me sometimes and what caused the behaviour was that some MyClass triggered an exception on its **str** method.

In such a case, PyCharm debugger only showed

`some_object = {MyClass} Unable to get repr for <class 'my_app.models.MyClass'>`

So what I did to confirm the origin was to watch `repr(some_object)` in the Watches section of the debugger.  And there it gave me an explicit error message:

`{TypeError}%d format: a number is required, not NoneType`

Which helped me trace back to the origin.

I appreciate this is not a generic answer, but just a complement to Fabio's.

Answer (score 2):

Probably some custom class of yours has a bad `__repr__` or `__str__` in it and the debugger is unable to print it.

You can probably use a shell at that point to know which elements are actually inside such a `dict` or `list` (and see which object has the faulty `__repr__` or `__str__`).

Answer (score 0):

Extending the scope of the problem rather than adding an answer - all the other suggestions are what I do normally to get this working.

Could it be a race condition?

For me it appears to be something weird. In the Variables pane I can see correct representation for `theObject`, `repr(theObject)` and even `[theObject]` but if I set a variable in my code thus `a = theObject` or `b = [theObject]` then I get the "Unable to get repr for <class 'list'>" message.

theObject in this case is an instance of a subclassed D lang struct wrapped with autowrap.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that __repr__was returning a dict and PyCharm is expecitng a string.

So, I modified the **repr** method like this:

```
    def __repr__(self):
      return str({
        'id': self.id,
        'email': self.email,
        'name': self.name
      })
```

This got rid of the Unable to get repr for... error